# ASP.Net VB SqlDataReader Format

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sqldatareader

I have a SqlDataReader that reads data from the database. How can I format the phone number to return as **(123) 456-7890** instead of 1234567890 on my aspx page? My reader as follow:  
`txtFaxPhone.Text = reader("FaxPhone").ToString()`

Comment: That bit is not hard. What do you want doing with null, blank shorter numbers, longer numbers. Already formatted numbers? Already formatted numbers is a different format..

Comment: @TonyHopkinson If null leave blank. numbers are not formatted. Just read data from the database and output to a phone number format. Thank you.

Comment: I figured it out by using: txtFaxPhone.Text = Format(PhoneFormat(reader("FaxPhone").ToString()))

Comment: Didn't even know there was a PhoneFormat. I shall remember that.

Comment: I don't think there is any PhoneFormat method,i think OP is using custom method that is already defined in their project.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson The reason the PhoneFormat worked was because I added a Public Shared Function PhoneFormat. So you are correct, there is no PhoneFormat method.

Comment: That's a pity, would have been handy. That would have been one of my suggestions, other would have been to do it in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
If reader.IsDbNull(reader.GetOrdinal("FaxPhone"))
   txtFaxPhone.Text = String.Empty
Else
   txtFaxPhone.Text = String.Format("(000) 000-0000", reader("FaxPhone"))
End If
```

Note:  this assumes your phone number is a number.  If it's a string, you'll have to substring it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and got the following error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: FaxNumber. How would you substring it?

Comment: Sounds like you used "FaxNumber" rather than "FaxPhone" as the field name.  Which one is it?